# How can I assist players navigating narrow grid junctions?

Tags: game-mechanics, grid, control, user-experience

I'm looking for a technique to help the player navigate a narrow path while the character is in constant motion. When changing direction in junctions, it's pretty hard to time the direction change for a successful turn. With bad timing, the character just gets stuck as pictured.

[image: pacman path]

How can I make this easier for the player? (This is for a university assignment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could "hot spot"-check areas adjacent to the character

[image: hot spot testing]

and immediately begin moving in a free direction if the appropriate movement key is held.

For example, if the player is moving right and holds the downward arrow key, they would continue moving right until the *below hot spot* becomes free. They would then begin moving down.

On platforms that allow multiple directional controls to be triggered simultaneously (such as the arrow keys on a PC), you may want to include an input [queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28abstract_data_type%29) in your control state to ensure the inputs process in order.

The original Pacman used a similar scheme, but even allowed the player to [cut corners](http://home.comcast.net/~jpittman2/pacman/pacmandossier.html#CH2_Cornering) if they held the controls in the appropriate direction ahead of time like this!

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it some thought. How would this translate to ghosts though, if at all? My initial thought was to have the turns/junctions mapped like the boxes are and those would define what directions are available. With an NPC I would then randomly pick one (it doesn't have to match the original AI, something simple is adequate).

Comment: You could apply the same to the ghosts, choosing a random direction when detecting an intersection. The [Pacman dossier](http://home.comcast.net/~jpittman2/pacman/pacmandossier.html) is a great resource for these things: It even describes the logic behind the ghosts' motion. (As you say, you could also model the grid as a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(data_structure)) or a number of other data types.)